# SSMS crashes instantly

Tags: sql-server

I have SSMS 2017 installed on my laptop.  Every time I start SSMS, it sits there for about 5 seconds, and it closes / crashes instantly without me clicking on anything.  I checked out the Event Viewer.  Here is what it shows:

1) .NET Runtime

> > Application: Ssms.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
> >     System.NotImplementedException    at
> >     System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlType(BamlType,
> >     Int16)    at
> >     System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.GetXamlType(Int16)    at
> >     System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_ElementStart()    at
> >     System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_OneBamlRecord()    at
> >     System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.ReadObject(System.Windows.Baml2006.KeyRecord)
> >     at
> >     System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.CreateObject(System.Windows.Baml2006.KeyRecord)
> >     at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnGettingValue(System.Object,
> >     System.Object ByRef, Boolean ByRef)    at
> >     System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnGettingValuePrivate(System.Object,
> >     System.Object ByRef, Boolean ByRef)    at
> >     System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValueWithoutLock(System.Object,
> >     Boolean ByRef)    at
> >     System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValue(System.Object, Boolean
> >     ByRef)    at
> >     System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.FetchResource(System.Object,
> >     Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef)    at
> >     System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindResourceInTree(System.Windows.FrameworkElement,
> >     System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement,
> >     System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Object, System.Object,
> >     Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.DependencyObject,
> >     System.Windows.InheritanceBehavior ByRef, System.Object ByRef)    at
> >     System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindResourceInternal(System.Windows.FrameworkElement,
> >     System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement,
> >     System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Object, System.Object,
> >     Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.DependencyObject, Boolean,
> >     System.Object ByRef)    at
> >     System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindImplicitStyleResource(System.Windows.FrameworkElement,
> >     System.Object, System.Object ByRef)    at
> >     System.Windows.FrameworkElement.GetRawValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty,
> >     System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
> >     ByRef)    at
> >     System.Windows.FrameworkElement.EvaluateBaseValueCore(System.Windows.DependencyProperty,
> >     System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
> >     ByRef)    at
> >     System.Windows.DependencyObject.EvaluateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex,
> >     System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata,
> >     System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry,
> >     System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.OperationType)
> >     at
> >     System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex,
> >     System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata,
> >     System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
> >     ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType)    at
> >     System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(System.Windows.DependencyProperty,
> >     Boolean)    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.UpdateStyleProperty()
> >     at
> >     System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.OnResourcesChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
> >     System.Windows.ResourcesChangeInfo, Boolean)    at
> >     System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateOnResourcesChange(System.Windows.FrameworkElement,
> >     System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement,
> >     System.Windows.ResourcesChangeInfo)    at
> >     System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.NotifyOwners(System.Windows.ResourcesChangeInfo)
> >     at
> >     System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.SetKeys(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1,
> >     System.IServiceProvider)    at
> >     System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.SetDeferrableContent(System.Windows.DeferrableContent)
> >     at
> >     System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfSharedBamlSchemaContext+<>c.b__297_0(System.Object,
> >     System.Object)    at
> >     System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(System.Object,
> >     System.Object)    at
> >     MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(System.Xaml.XamlMember,
> >     System.Object, System.Object)    at
> >     MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(System.Object,
> >     System.Xaml.XamlMember, System.Object)
>
> Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader,
>   System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object,
>   System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader,
>   Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel,
>   System.Uri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream,
>   System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Object, System.Uri)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VsStatusBar.InitializeComponent()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.WorkerThreadStatusBarContainer.CreateRootUIElement()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.WorkerThreadElementContainer.CreateHostedVisualWorker()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    at
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr,
>   IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)    at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr,
>   Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>   at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
>   ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.BackgroundDispatcher.ThreadProc(System.Object)
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(System.Object)

2) Application Error

> ```
> Faulting application name: Ssms.exe, version: 2017.140.17119.0, time stamp: 0x591bcf8a 
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
> 6.1.7601.23864, time stamp: 0x595fa536 
> Exception code: 0xe0434352 
> Fault offset: 0x0000c54f 
> Faulting process id: 0x250c 
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d337a827d6ebfc 
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe 
> Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id: 6f1ce4e3-a39b-11e7-9593-b8763fd92420
> ```

3) Windows Error Reporting

> > Fault bucket 500, type 5 Event Name: CLR20r3 Response: Not available Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature: P1: Ssms.exe P2: 2017.140.17119.0 P3: 591bcf8a P4:
>   PresentationFramework P5: 4.6.1099.0 P6: 58d87db9 P7: f9b P8: 5b P9:
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse P10:

Why is this happening, and what must I do to resolve it?

Comment: do you have all windows updates up to date and also can you try upgrading to latest version of ssms

Comment: Yes, I have all Windows updates.  (I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise, SP1.)  And, actually, I had the same thing happen with SSMS v17.2.  So, I downgraded to v17.14.

Comment: Have you tried either a Server Service Stop and Start or a simply re-boot the workstation to see if these fixes it? Also see if there is a pending Windows update requiring a reboot.

Comment: I tried rebooting my laptop multiple times, but it didn't resolve the issue.  I can't Restart the SQL service, since I get an error stating that I can't connect to the WMI provider.  (My laptop doesn't host the servers I need to hit.)  And, I don't have the access to update Windows.  (In fact Windows updates are blocked on my laptop.)

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same problem with the exact same error NotImplementedException in the Event Viewer. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact same issue with SSMS 17.9 and it seemed to have been caused when I uninstalled one out of my two versions of Microsoft Visual Studio that were on my computer.

After two days of attempting Re-install just SSMS, Repair, SSMS, trying to repair my .NET files, rebooting, and clearing files out of the appdata directory,
the only thing that resolved the issue for me was uninstalling all the following programs:

- SSMS
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated)
- Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015
- Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015 Language support

Then I ran the SSMS installer again, which installs all three of the other programs as well as SSMS. I have not seen the issue again since I have done this.

Hopefully this helps!!